# Check if TextFieldTableCell equals something on edit commit?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am using a custom `TextFieldTableCell` in JavaFX 8 to allow users to edit the text field.  When the user hits Enter, however, I want to check to see if the text field equals a certain value.  If it does equal this certain value, I do not want the entry to save and for it to revert to the text it had before the user started editing.  Is there a method I can override to produce this result?  I cannot find one that fits what I am looking for.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the model is bound to the cell's data, you can do the validation and reset part in the modell class, in your case in the `Person` class.

Here is a simple example how you can do it:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, String> name;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Model> tableView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        name.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().nameProperty());
        name.setCellFactory(cell -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(new StringConverter<String>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(String object) {
                return object;
            }

            @Override
            public String fromString(String string) {
                return string;
            }
        }));
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Model("Test")));

    }

    private class Model {
        private StringProperty name;

        ChangeListener<String> nameChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*")) { // a validation example insert your here.
                this.name.set(oldValue);
            }
        };

        public Model(String name) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.name.addListener(nameChangeListener);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: yeah, let the model protect its own integrety is fine (and actually necessary always, it must not rely on outsiders to do so) - but if you use a listener approach there's no need to add/remove the listener, provided you start off with valid value which is a must anyway ;). An alternative (my preference) is a custom property with an overridden invalidated that's doing the validation.

Comment: Yeah, you are  right, I got SOException before, that is why I add/remove it, but after retesting  without it works. I am updating the answer. I would like to see your approach with overridden `invalidated()` since I never used it I have no idea what to do there ;)

Comment: have a look at core classes - they do it often (not on my IDE, so can't be more specific right now, sry)

Comment: I could solve it using `invalidated()`, it is a very nice  approach, thank you for the suggestion ;) As you said yesterday, I also learnt something today ;)

Answer (score -1):

From your description I assume that you are talking about an editable cell in a table view.

If that's the case, the following example should be working for you. You can use the .setOnEditCommit() method to add an event handler to the colum for which you would like to check the entered value.

```
    //Create table
    TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    table.setEditable(true);

    //Create column
    TableColumn<Person, String> column = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Full Name");
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fullName"));
    column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person> forTableColumn());
    column.setMinWidth(200);

    column.setOnEditCommit(event -> {

        //Get entered value
        String newFullName = event.getNewValue();

        //Get selected position
        TablePosition<Person, String> pos = event.getTablePosition();

        //Get row of position
        int row = pos.getRow();

        //Get data from selected row
        Person person = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);

        //Check if text equals ...
        if (newFullName.equals("Test")) {
            person.setFullName(newFullName);
        } else {
            person.setFullName(event.getOldValue());
            table.refresh();
        }
    });
```

Comment: basically okay, but: never-ever (as in 99.99999%) use table.refresh - if it seems necessary then most probably something is wrong in your setup!

Comment: Instead of 'table.refresh' you could also "update" the table by using table.getColumns().get(col).setVisible(false) and afterwards table.getColumns().get(col).setVisible(true);

Comment: nononono that's even worse ... instead of doing the wrong thingy (in whatever form) setup your data correctly then the update happens automagically!

Comment: What would you suggest so that the data is set up correctly? I'm open for any better solutions than mine.

Comment: if it doesn't work automagically then something is wrong in the code you are not showing - my crystal ball is too lazy to guess ;) Post a question and somebody will probably look into your issue. Anyway, I don't understand why you need the resetting to old value at all: at that point nothing is committed, so your data is unchanged. If that's not reflected in the cell, then it might be a bug in the cell implementation (which has a non-zero probability ;)